# I can't save a matlab function

Tags: function, matlab, project

I was trying to save a function I needed for a project. This is my first time using this version and I don't know how to fix this issue. How do I get the permission[image: This is the window that pops up]

Comment: save it to a folder you have permission to write files with... start a folder in "my documents" ans save it there...

Comment: The folder you're attempting to save to houses matlab's binaries... e.g. the stuff your computer uses to actually open and execute matlab. You probably don't want to be saving .m files there as it could potentially mess up your matlab installation. @bla's answer is a good one... just save the file somewhere else. Alternatively, you can probably log in as administrator on windows if you really want to save the file to the bin folder.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can try to save your .m file in another Folder.